# I am unable to catch the exception created when querying a non existent SAP HANA table using pyodbc/python

Tags: python, sql, exception, pyodbc, hana

I want to create a new table if I query a table that ends up being non existent. I thought to do this via catching the exception generated, but I can unable to do that despite specifying the error that pops up in my except statement.
Each of the try blocks I have below lead the two exception at the end.

```
import pyodbc as py
    
qry = \
"""
SELECT * 
FROM NON_EXISTENT_TABLE 
"""

cmd = \
    """
    CREATE TABLE  SOME_TABLE(VAR1 VARCHAR(10), 
    VAR2 VARCHAR(50), VAR3 VARCHAR(5), VAR4 VARCHAR(6));   
    """


try:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, py.connect('DSN=SOMEDSN; Trusted_Connection = Yes'))
except py.ProgrammingError:
    py.connect('DSN=SOMEDSN; Trusted_Connection=Yes').cursor().execute(cmd)    


try:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, py.connect('DSN=SOMEDSN; Trusted_Connection = Yes'))
except py.DatabaseError:
    py.connect('DSN=SOMEDSN; Trusted_Connection=Yes').cursor().execute(cmd)
```

This is the error I get

```
ProgrammingError: ('42S02', '[42S02] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] Base table or view not found;259 invalid table name:  Could not find table/view NON_EXISTENT_TABLE in schema SOMESCHEMA: line 3 col 15 (at pos 25) (259) (SQLExecDirectW)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '
SELECT * 
FROM SOMESCHEMA.NON_EXISTENT_TABLE
': ('42S02', '[42S02] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] Base table or view not found;259 invalid table name:  Could not find table/view NON_EXISTENT_TABLE in schema SOMESCHEMA: line 3 col 15 (at pos 25) (259) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to provide an answer on the specific Python issue. However, it may be helpful for you to know, that SAP offers an [advanced Python client for SAP HANA](https://pypi.org/project/hana-ml/), which makes life a lot easier especially when working with Pandas dataframes.

With the [hana-ml client](http://%E2%88%9A), you can use function [`has_table`](https://help.sap.com/doc/1d0ebfe5e8dd44d09606814d83308d4b/2.0.06/en-US/hana_ml.dataframe.html#hana_ml.dataframe.ConnectionContext.has_table) to check if a table exists. Depending on the outcome you may use function [`create_table`](https://help.sap.com/doc/1d0ebfe5e8dd44d09606814d83308d4b/2.0.06/en-US/hana_ml.dataframe.html#hana_ml.dataframe.ConnectionContext.create_table) to create a new table. Finally you can use the [HANA Dataframe](https://help.sap.com/doc/1d0ebfe5e8dd44d09606814d83308d4b/2.0.06/en-US/hana_ml.dataframe.html#) to query data and [`collect`](https://help.sap.com/doc/1d0ebfe5e8dd44d09606814d83308d4b/2.0.06/en-US/hana_ml.dataframe.html#hana_ml.dataframe.DataFrame.collect) the result as a Pandas dataframe.

Comment: Thanks so much Mathias. I will look into that!